# selenium webdriver in python. any 3rd party libs?

Tags: python, webdriver

are there any 3rd party libs at all in python that do something **on top of webdriver**?

I am considering using [selenium webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-webdriver) in python, but i would really like to use a [ui-module based approach](http://code.google.com/p/aost/). What i mean by that is instead of code that might look like this:

```
cheese = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#food span.dairy.aged")
cheese.click()
```

i want something like (not python!):

```
   ui.Div(uid: "div1", clocator: [id: "div1"]) {
      Div(uid: "inner-container", clocator: [id: "div2"]) {
        List(uid: "list1", clocator: [tag: "ul"], separator: "li"){
          UrlLink(uid: "{all}", clocator: [:])
        }
      } 
   }
   click 'inner-container'
```

So I define my UI beforehand, and then write the testcases. If the UI changes, I need to change the UI module definition and not worry about the testcases.

I can hand roll this, but are there any libs for python that do this for me?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't Tellurium (the link you gave) just a DSL for Selenium? So why not just use that?

Comment: its a DSL written in groovy, so if i were to use it, id have to roll my own in python, which i might end up doing, but i wanted to know if there are existing alternatives. also tellurium uses selenium 1.x (not webdriver) thus i cant use it straight up

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately, I don't know of any existing equivalents for Python, so rolling your own may be your best bet.

Comment: Would you mind to explain what this non Python code does? We could try to suggest something if we know what at all you are trying to achieve - specially without learning a new concept of a new library in a new language!

Comment: check out the tellurium link i posted and the introduction there. basically the only thing i care about is being able to define a 'model' of my pages separately from the tests, that way if the pages change all i need to do is change the model and not the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no existing project that I am aware of that does what you want. One pattern that I've been using in my functional tests with Webdriver is to define each logical page as a class. Something like this:

```
class LoginPage(object):

    def __init__(self, testcase):
        self.tc = testcase

    def login(self, username, password, at_login_page=False):
        if not at_login_page:
            self.tc.browser.get(self.tc.ROOT + '/login')

        self.tc.browser.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys(username)
        self.tc.browser.find_element_by_id('id_password').send_keys(password)
        login_button = self.tc.browser.find_element_by_id('login-button').click()
```

And then use it in in the test like so, where 'self' in this case is an instance of unit test :

```
    login_page = site_pages.LoginPage(self)
    login_page.login(self.username, self.password)
```

Using this pattern might get you close to what you want to do. The way a page works is logically contained in the class methods, instead of being endlessly repeated through each functional test.

Answer (score 1):

The [robot framework](http://www.robotframework.org) has a [library for selenium](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library) that lets you write tests using plain text keywords. For example:

```
| Simple test case
| | open browser | http://example.com
| | click link | //some-crazy/xpath
| | page should contain | blah blah blah
```

Robotframework is written in python. Is that something you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/)? You can use jQuery-style selectors.

Comment: this doesnt seem to based on selenium, but thats ok. Do you know what the differences are between selenium and this?